# Как узнать внутри wcf службы, сколько раз клиент вызывал определенный метод у службы

Tags: c#, wcf

Всем здравствуйте, есть у меня wcf служба, она работает, встал вопрос, как мне узнать, сколько раз клиент вызывал метод определенный. нужно  это для того, чтобы например клиент в клиентском приложении кликнул три раза на кнопку Заказать,а мне нужно, чтобы четвертый раз он не кликнул,  и в ответ служба пришлет ему ограничение мол ваш лимит исчерпан. Вопрос куда посмотреть, как можно  организовать такой учет. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Такой функциональности из коробки нет. Запоминайте вызовы, считайте, может быть даже - сохраняйте в базу. А когда понадобится считайте - сколько вызовов было за период

Comment: @AK Да я так и думал. а как тогда эти вызовы запомнить, где их увидеть. Или  в лоб как то из метода исполняемого сигналить?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch переопределите IOperationInvoker через пользовательское поведение (behavior). Ну или в лоб из исполняемог7о метода сигнальте...